# How to switch between tabs opened in gnome-terminal and also close any particular tab using shortcut key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I can open as many terminal tabs I want using <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

But for some reason, I'm not able to switch the tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>. So what is the shortcut-key to switch in between tabs?

Also, what do I do to close any particular tabs using the shortcut keys?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can switch the tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to next tabs and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> for the previous tabs.

Reordering can be done using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

Also <kbd>Alt+1</kbd> to <kbd>Alt + 0</kbd> can be used to switch tabs starting from 1 to 10. Where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is for **1st** tab in terminal, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is for **2nd** tab ... <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> is for **10th** tab.

If more than 10 tabs are opened then you've to switch using the shortcut mentioned above. i,e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

To close any selected tabs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: I'll check and let you know whether it's working or not. Currently I'm not able to check it. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **PgUp/PgDn** actually switching my tabs numbering. i,e 1st tab becomes 2nd and, 2nd becomes 1st. But others are working perfectly.. Thanks.. :D

Answer (score 8):

`gnome-terminal` shortcuts can also be customized, which is very easy and useful, if you use different applications that ought to have set the same shortcut(s) [applies only to the current active application] for the same/similar function(s).

**Example**: Closing tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> shortcut in `gnome-terminal` and `geany` (text-editor)

In "gnome-terminal" under "Edit" -▸ "Keyboard Shortcuts" (see screenshots below) you can set your custom shortcuts.

If you use the same setup as shown below, and lets say you have three tabs open, you can simple switch between them with:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - Switch to Tab1
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - Switch to Tab2
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> - Switch to Tab3
- And also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left-arrow</kbd>key or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>rigth-arrow</kbd>key - to switch from left to right through your tabs and vice versa!

Once you activated tab 1/2/3 you can then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to close it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks.. It seems to be new features added to gnome terminal though I'm not sure.. :) but it is really helpful..

Comment: You are welcome Saurav Kumar. How long this option is available now I can not say for sure. I noticed it in v. 11.10 - Oneiric Ocelot.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to change it to the standard Ctrl-Tab for Next Tab?

Comment: Double-click the shortcut-key of Next Tab and input whatever new shortcut-key combination you'd prefer.

Comment: Ctrl+W, Ctrl+T, Ctrl+N, etc. make a lot of sense since the same shortcuts are used almost everywhere else (e.g. browsers, text editor, etc.). Making them Ctrl+Shift+W, Ctrl+Shift+T, etc. also makes a lot of sense as Ctrl+W, Ctrl+C, etc. are usually used for other bindings. However, something that also makes a lot of sense is Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab. And for whatever reason, `gnome-terminal` does not let me set the shortcut to that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what works is: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab number</kbd>.